# Updating current location using Geolocator Streams in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I was under the impression that using `getPositionStream` from the `geolocator` package would update my current location as per the value specified in the `distanceFilter` property. However, it hasn't quite turned out to be how I expected. It doesn't seem to update the address once that distance has been covered. I would like to know what I need to do to get this to work the way I want. Here's the code below:

locationPermissions.dart(The code with stream is in the `getAddressFromLocationTwo` method. I have marked that with a comment as well)

```
class LocationProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  
  LocationProvider() {
    getLocation();
  }

  String _address = '';
  String _deliveryAddress = '';
  String _state = '';
  String? postCode;
  String? addressLine;
  String _locality = '';
  String? city;
  String? selectedState;
  late LocationSettings locationSettings;
  var defaultTargetPlatform;

  bool isLoading = true;

  bool get loading {
    return isLoading;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> _coorDinates = {'lat': 0.0, 'lng': 0.0};

  Map<String, dynamic> get coorDinates {
    return {..._coorDinates};
  }

  String? get state {
    return _state;
  }

  String get address {
    return _address;
  }

  String get deliveryAddress {
    return _deliveryAddress;
  }

  String get locality {
    return _locality;
  }

  Future<Position> _getGeoLocationPosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
  }

  Future<void> getAddressFromLatLong(Position position) async {
    List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
        position.latitude, position.longitude,
        localeIdentifier: 'en');
    print(placemarks);
    Placemark place = placemarks[0];
    _address = '${place.subLocality}';
    _deliveryAddress =
        '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}';
    _state = place.administrativeArea!;

    postCode = place.postalCode!;
    addressLine = '${place.street} ${place.thoroughfare}';
    _locality = place.subLocality!;
    city = place.locality!;
    selectedState = place.administrativeArea!;

    print('Initial Address $postCode');
    print('Initial Address $addressLine');
    print('Initial Address $locality');
    print('Initial Address $city');
    print('Initial Address $selectedState');

    _coorDinates['lat'] = position.latitude;
    _coorDinates['lng'] = position.longitude;
    print('Delivery Address: $_deliveryAddress');
    print('Coordinates in Location ${_coorDinates['lat']}');
    print('Coordinates in Location ${_coorDinates['lng']}');
    // setState(() {});
    notifyListeners();
  }


  //This is the method that has Stream in it
  Future<void> getAddressFromLocationTwo(Position position) async {        
    if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      locationSettings = AndroidSettings(
          accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
          distanceFilter: 100,
          forceLocationManager: true,
          intervalDuration: const Duration(seconds: 10),
          //(Optional) Set foreground notification config to keep the app alive
          //when going to the background
          foregroundNotificationConfig: const ForegroundNotificationConfig(
            notificationText:
                "Example app will continue to receive your location even when you aren't using it",
            notificationTitle: "Running in Background",
            enableWakeLock: true,
          ));
    } else if (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS ||
        defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.macOS) {
      locationSettings = AppleSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
        activityType: ActivityType.fitness,
        distanceFilter: 100,
        pauseLocationUpdatesAutomatically: false,
        // Only set to true if our app will be started up in the background.
        showBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
      );
    } else {
      locationSettings = const LocationSettings(
        accuracy: LocationAccuracy.best,
        distanceFilter: 100,
      );
    }

    StreamSubscription<Position> positionStream =
        Geolocator.getPositionStream(locationSettings: locationSettings)
            .listen((Position? position) async {
      // print(position == null
      //     ? 'Unknown'
      //     : '${position.latitude.toString()}, ${position.longitude.toString()}');
      List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          position!.latitude, position.longitude,
          localeIdentifier: 'en');
      print('PLACEMARKKKKKKKKKS: $placemarks');
      Placemark place = placemarks[0];
      _address = '${place.subLocality}';
      _deliveryAddress =
          '${place.street}, ${place.subLocality}, ${place.locality}, ${place.postalCode}, ${place.country}';
      _state = place.administrativeArea!;

      postCode = place.postalCode!;
      addressLine = '${place.street} ${place.thoroughfare}';
      _locality = place.subLocality!;
      city = place.locality!;
      selectedState = place.administrativeArea!;

      print('Initial Address $postCode');
      print('Initial Address $addressLine');
      print('Initial Address $locality');
      print('Initial Address $city');
      print('Initial Address $selectedState');

      _coorDinates['lat'] = position.latitude;
      _coorDinates['lng'] = position.longitude;
      print('Delivery Address: $_deliveryAddress');
      print('Coordinates in Location ${_coorDinates['lat']}');
      print('Coordinates in Location ${_coorDinates['lng']}');
      // setState(() {});
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  Future<void> getLocation() async {
    Position position = await _getGeoLocationPosition();
    getAddressFromLatLong(position);
    getAddressFromLocationTwo(position);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

The widget where this method is being used:

```
class AttendanceWidgetState extends State<AttendanceWidget> {
  String? currentLocation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getLocation()
        .then((_) {
      setState(() {
        addressLoader = false;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<Position> _getGeoLocationPosition() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      await Geolocator.openLocationSettings();
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }

    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation);
  }

  Future<void> autoRefreshLocation() async {
    Position position = await _getGeoLocationPosition();
    Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getAddressFromLatLong(position)
        .then((_) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .deliveryAddress;
        addressLoader = false;
      });
    });
  }

  void getCurrentLocation() async {
    Position position = await _getGeoLocationPosition();

    Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
        .getAddressFromLocationTwo(position)
        .then((_) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = Provider.of<LocationProvider>(context, listen: false)
            .deliveryAddress;
      });
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            Future.delayed(
                const Duration(seconds: 8), () => Navigator.of(context).pop());
            return CupertinoAlertDialog(
              content: Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Current Address: $currentLocation!'),
                  value > radius
                      ? Text(
                          'Invalid Location: You are ${value.toStringAsFixed(0)} Metre(s) away from Office')
                      : Text(
                          'You are within ${value.toStringAsFixed(0)} Metre(s) of Office')
                ],
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context); //close Dialog
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Close',
                    style: Theme.of(context)
                        .textTheme
                        .bodyText1!
                        .copyWith(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    });

    print('LOCATIONNNNNNNNNN: $currentLocation');
    print('DISTANCE DIFFERENCE: $value');
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    

    // TODO: implement build
    return ClipRRect(
      
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  // color: Colors.amber,
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        flex: 1,
                        fit: FlexFit.tight,
                        child: Container(
                          height: double.infinity,
                          // color: Colors.green,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: [
                              Flexible(
                                flex: 1,
                                fit: FlexFit.tight,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: double.infinity,
                                  // color: Colors.pink,
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  child: InkWell(
                                    onTap: () => getCurrentLocation(),  
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: double.infinity,
                                      height: double.infinity,
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                          SizeVariables.getHeight(context) *
                                              0.01),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          color: Theme.of(context)
                                              .colorScheme
                                              .tertiary,
                                          borderRadius:
                                              BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                          boxShadow: [
                                            BoxShadow(
                                                color: Colors.grey
                                                    .withOpacity(0.5),
                                                spreadRadius: 1,
                                                blurRadius: 7,
                                                offset: Offset(4, 2))
                                          ]),
                                      child: addressLoader
                                          ? Center(
                                              child: Lottie.asset(
                                                  'assets/json/location.json',
                                                  height: 350,
                                                  width: 350))
                                          // const Center(
                                          //     child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                                          //   )
                                          : Column(
                                              crossAxisAlignment:
                                                  CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                              children: [
                                                Flexible(
                                                  flex: 1,
                                                  child: Container(
                                                    // color: Colors.blue,
                                                    width: double.infinity,
                                                    child: Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                          MainAxisAlignment
                                                              .spaceBetween,
                                                      children: [
                                                        SizedBox(
                                                          child: Row(
                                                            children: [
                                                              Icon(
                                                                  Icons
                                                                      .location_on,
                                                                  color: Theme.of(
                                                                          context)
                                                                      .accentColor,
                                                                  size: SizeVariables
                                                                          .getHeight(
                                                                              context) *
                                                                      0.02),
                                                              Text(
                                                                  'Current Location',
                                                                  style: Theme.of(
                                                                          context)
                                                                      .textTheme
                                                                      .bodyText1!
                                                                      .copyWith(
                                                                        fontSize:
                                                                            10,
                                                                      ))
                                                            ],
                                                          ),
                                                        ),
                                                        InkWell(
                                                          onTap: () =>
                                                              getCurrentLocation(),
                                                          child: Icon(
                                                              Icons.refresh,
                                                              color: Theme.of(
                                                                      context)
                                                                  .accentColor,
                                                              size: SizeVariables
                                                                      .getHeight(
                                                                          context) *
                                                                  0.02),
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                SizedBox(
                                                  height:
                                                      SizeVariables.getHeight(
                                                              context) *
                                                          0.01,
                                                ),
                                                Container(
                                                  // color: Colors.red,
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    currentLocation!,
                                                    style: Theme.of(context)
                                                        .textTheme
                                                        .bodyText1!
                                                        .copyWith(
                                                          fontSize: 8,
                                                        ),
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                     
    );
  }
```